# SQL Query DATEDIFF date time fields result in minutes

Tags: sql, datediff

Can anyone tell me how to write the SQL Query to calculate the time difference between 2 columns that are stored as `DATETIME` columns and get the result in minutes...

For example:

Table structure

```
ID, start-time, end-time
```

I want to do a select on a specific ID and perform a calculation of the  end-time - start-time and return the result in minutes only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql : [TimeStampDiff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, start_time, end_time)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1;
```

SqlServer: [DATEDIFF](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(n, start_time, end_time)
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = 1;
```

Comment: Can you please update your question and add the tag `sql server` or `mysql` tag as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server, you can use [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, start-time, end-time) FROM tableName where id=1;
```