# How do I get the minute difference between 2 times in T SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I get the "minutes" difference between 2 times in T SQL?  I tried DATEDIFF, but it obviously wants dates.  This would be the difference in minutes between 2 times in a day.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` works with time values as well

Comment: What is the data type of your time data and show some examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query DATEDIFF date time fields result in minutes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164002/sql-query-datediff-date-time-fields-result-in-minutes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think DATEDIFF would be your best option.  I know you are looking for the difference in time within the same day, but couldn't you just pass DATEDIFF two DateTime types with the same date, but different times?

```
// Should return 300
DATEDIFF(mi, '2015-02-19 08:00:00', '2015-02-19 13:00:00')
```

Comment: I'm sensing it's the format I have...I have two nvarchar values like "4:00 PM". So - I need to convert. Not sure how?

Comment: Thank You - I needed to convert the date to 24 hour first.  Then this did the trick!  Thank You Pat!

Answer (score 2):

`DateDiff` not only work with `Date` datatype it even accepts `TIME` datatype.

Even if your `datatype` is `nvarchar` it will work but it should be a valid `time`.

**Simple Demo**

```
create table time_test(a nvarchar(50),b nvarchar(50))

insert time_test values ('4:00 PM','4:30 PM')

select datediff(minute,a,b) from time_test --30
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually works for me:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, @StarTime, @endTime)
```