# SQL comparison of two dates

Tags: sql

I have two dates in a SQL database stored as `datetime`: `SALE_ORDER.LMOD_HOST` and `SALE_ORDER.CREATION_TS`

The format of both dates is as follows:

```
2020-01-20 12:46:15.220
```

If I want to compare the two in a SQL statement, how can I check to see if both are within a minute of each other?

Something like:

```
  where left(SALE_ORDER.LMOD_HOST,16) = left(SALE_ORDER.CREATION_TS,16)
```

So the comparison would be `2020-01-20 12:46` against `2020-01-20 12:46`

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Please do not say you are storing dates as strings.  If that is the case, then fix the data *first*.  Then address the question.  Databases have built-in data types for a reason.

Comment: Hi, both dates are stored as datetime in a sql database

Comment: what db are you using?

Comment: SQL Database I am using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the minute difference between 2 times in T SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612851/how-do-i-get-the-minute-difference-between-2-times-in-t-sql)

Comment: No, I just want to check that two dates are the same up to the minute. Do not mind about the second.

Comment: @glh "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". And date/time functions are highly vendor specific. In Postgres you could use `date_trunc()` in Oracle you could use `trunc()` for this

Comment: it may works `DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL value addunit)`

Comment: Comparing `2020-01-20 12:46` with `2020-01-20 12:46` is something different than within a minute because `12:46:30` would be in a minute with `12:45:40` and `12:47:20`. So you have to calculate the difference and check if it's between `+- 1 minute`.

Answer (score 0):

Datetime functions are notoriously database dependent.  In standard SQL you would use:

```
where lSALE_ORDER.LMOD_HOST < SALE_ORDER.CREATION_TS + interval '1 minute'
```

I am assuming the creation is always earlier.

In SQL Server (which a discouraging number of people refer to just as "SQL", causing lots of confusion):

```
where lSALE_ORDER.LMOD_HOST < dateadd(minute, 1, SALE_ORDER.CREATION_TS)
```